# A point of sale application using ArrayList of Item class. How to return isolated/specific values from the list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Java noob here. I am trying to build a simple point of sale checkout application. I have a simple item database in mysql shown in the pic below.

[image]

I have an Item class built as below with getters and setters for each column

```
public class Item {
private String itemName;
private double unitPrice;
private boolean weightReqd;
private boolean quanReqd;
private boolean recalled;
private boolean ageRest;
private boolean eCpn;
private double eCpnAmt;

public Item(){}

public Item(String itemName, double unitPrice, boolean weightReqd, boolean quanReqd, boolean recalled,
            boolean ageRest, boolean eCpn, double eCpnAmt){
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.weightReqd = weightReqd;
    this.quanReqd = quanReqd;
    this.recalled = recalled;
    this.ageRest = ageRest;
    this.eCpn = eCpn;
    this.eCpnAmt = eCpnAmt;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

public double getUnitPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(double unitPrice) {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
}

public boolean isWeightReqd() {
    return weightReqd;
}

public void setWeightReqd(boolean weightReqd) {
    this.weightReqd = weightReqd;
}

public boolean isQuanReqd() {
    return quanReqd;
}

public void setQuanReqd(boolean quanReqd) {
    this.quanReqd = quanReqd;
}

public boolean isRecalled() {
    return recalled;
}

public void setRecalled(boolean recalled) {
    this.recalled = recalled;
}

public boolean isAgeRest() {
    return ageRest;
}

public void setAgeRest(boolean ageRest) {
    this.ageRest = ageRest;
}

public boolean iseCpn() {
    return eCpn;
}

public void seteCpn(boolean eCpn) {
    this.eCpn = eCpn;
}

public double geteCpnAmt() {
    return eCpnAmt;
}

public void seteCpnAmt(double eCpnAmt) {
    this.eCpnAmt = eCpnAmt;
}
```

}

And then i am using setters from the Item class to add the records to a List of Items (List).

```
public class CreateItemList {

private static Connection conn = null;
public List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

public void createDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itemdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "******", "*********");
}

public void addItemsToList() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM item_source";
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    try
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setItemName(rs.getString("Item Name"));
            item.setUnitPrice(rs.getDouble("Unit Price"));
            item.setWeightReqd(rs.getBoolean("Weight Reqd"));
            item.setQuanReqd(rs.getBoolean("Quan Reqd"));
            item.setRecalled(rs.getBoolean("Recall"));
            item.setAgeRest(rs.getBoolean("Age Rest"));
            item.seteCpn(rs.getBoolean("Ecpn"));
            item.seteCpnAmt(rs.getDouble("Ecpn Amt"));

            itemList.add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    st.close();
}
```

}

Now the next thing i want to do is create exception handler methods. So if the user enters an item that is flagged as "true" for weight required, i want the is WeightReqd method to return true. But I'm struggling on this. I'm not sure how to return the boolean value for the item scanned, specifically for the Weight Reqd field.

```
public class ExceptionsHandler {

public boolean isWeightReqd(List<Item> itemList){
   //HOW DO I RETURN THE BOOLEAN VALUE FOR THE WEIGHT REQD FIELD FROM THE LIST?? 
   return false;
}
```

Would really appreciate the help! Can also take instructions on the general structure of this program, if there are better ways to do it!

Comment: I don't get your question. You have a list of Items, each having WeightReqd set to true or false. Which one you want to return?

Comment: Before you add the item to the list, you need to pass the item itself (not the list as you are doing now) to evaluate if the flag is true or false and accordingly decide it. Now you are passing the list instead of an individual item.

Comment: @user7 Totally understand. It's a bit confusing..So i would ask the user to enter an item using the scanner..I'll take that string and look through the list if it's there. If it is there, then i want it to return the boolean value for that item. So let's say they enter "Banana"..the Weight Reqd boolean value for banana is true, so i would want the method to return true for that.

Comment: So, would you pass the Item entered by the user to isWeightReqd method along with the List of items from DB? In that case, it has to have two parameters.

Comment: Would reccomend using maps instead. Banana = key, false = value, you can use the hasKey() method to check if the user's input is one of the keys....

Comment: @user7 Yes, i thought about that too. I i guess the method signature would be "public boolean isWeightReqd(List<Item> itemList, String itemScanned)", but i still am not grasping how to return the "weight required" boolean value for that specific item?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your ExceptionHandler class for a specific item scanned. You dont need to pass the whole list in your isWeightReqd() method. Only pass  your Item. Change your method signature to: `public boolean isWeightReqd(Item itemList)` and should get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where a hashmap might make more sense than an arraylist, using the name of the item as a key. Regardless once you have found that item all you need to call is

```
boolean b = item.isWeightReqd();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your inputs in the comments, the user will enter the `Item Name` of an item and you want to return whether weight is required or not. So, the method signature would have the list of items from the DB and the item name entered by the user.

**Option 1:**

 You can stream the contents of the list, find the item whose `itemName` matches the one entered by the user and return its `weightReqd`.

```
public boolean isWeightReqd(List<Item> itemList, String itemScanned) {
    return itemList.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getItemName().equals(itemScanned))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Item::isWeightReqd)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("The item " + itemScanned 
                + " does not exist"));
}
```

However, the worst-case running time for this is O(n) if the item scanned is not present or if it is the last one in the list.

**Option 2:**

 If you want an O(1) lookup, you can convert the `List<Item>` after fetching it from the DB as a Map whose key is the `itemName` and value is the `Item` itself.

```
Map<String, Item> items = itemList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getItemName, Function.identity()));

public boolean isWeightReqd(List<Item> itemList, String itemScanned) {
    if (items.containsKey(itemScanned)) {
        return items.get(itemScanned).isWeightReqd();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("The item " + itemScanned + " does not exist");
}
```

---

```
  //Or by using Optional
  Optional.ofNullable(items.get(itemScanned))
            .map(Item::isWeightReqd)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("The item " + itemScanned
                    + " does not exist"));
```